# Return TRUE/FALSE if common elements/no common elements between vectors

Tags: r, vector, equality, intersect

I'm looking for an efficient way to create a boolean vector which returns `TRUE` if one or more of *a number* of specified variables e.g. `c(1,2,3)` are in another vector e.g. `c(4,5,6,1)`.

In this example the output sought would be `TRUE` as the element `1` is present in both vectors.

As far as I know `%in%` only permits checking one variable at a time and using the `|` operator is inefficient in this case given the number of potential variables I need to check for. Using `intersect()` returns `logical(0)` rather than `FALSE`, and `sum(c(1,2,3) == c(4,5,6,1)) > 1` returns `FALSE` as the common elements are not in the same position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option:

```
vector1 <- c(1,2,3)
vector2 <- c(4,5,6,1)

any(Reduce(intersect, list(vector1, vector2)))
```

Output:

```
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: All correct answers here, but this solution works with ```group_by``` which was what I needed.

Comment: All of the solutions work with group_by.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `any`:

```r
vec <- c(1,2,3)
vec2 <- c(4,5,6,1)

any(vec %in% vec2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `any` is the most efficient way, but just to offer another solution, here's one using `sum`:

```
!!sum(c(1,2,3) %in% c(4,5,6,1))

 # [1] TRUE
```

Or we can use `length`:

```
length(base::intersect(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6,1))) != 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option using `is.element` with `any`:

```
vec1 <- c(1,2,3)
vec2 <- c(4,5,6,1)

any(is.element(vec1, vec2))

# [1] TRUE
```

Or another option is to use `match` with `any` (though would probably be less efficient):

```
any(match(vec1, vec2), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

One more
not great option:

```
anyDuplicated( c(unique(vec), unique(vec2)) ) > 0
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** As commented by @M-- in case of no matches it gives back TRUE! Here is how to avoid this:

```
!all(!(v1 %in% v2))
```

**First answer:**
One more with negating `all`:

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
v2 <- c(4,5,6,1)

!all(v1 %in% v2)
```

```
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This comes back true if there are no matches at all.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this one!. Here is how it works:  `!all(!v1 %in% v2)`

Comment: ```!all(!(v1 %in% v2))```